# Rendering errors with GeForce GTX 960m

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

For quite a while now, maybe it has always been like this, I'm experiencing rendering errors in any application running on my GPU (GTX 960m). If I chose to run the application on my Intel Graphics Card everything is working fine. The errors are always similar and are visible when something like a straight line is moving from one side of the screen to the other (Easier to see if it's moving horizontally). The error I'm seeing is that one or multiple parts of the line get shifted to the left or right.

Since taking screenshots seems to be impossible, here's a drawing of the error:

[image: drawing of the error].

I am using the latest driver version and I've already sent my laptop in and had the Mainboard (including the GPU) + Display replaced but the same error still persists. 
If anyone has an idea on what might be the problem or if you need more information, please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have bad news, what you describe, can only be described by a hardware problem.

Comment: I thought so too, but I had that problem before I sent my laptop in, and after I got it back with a new mainboard (including gpu) and a new display it's still the same .

Answer (score 0):

enable vsync and triple buffering.

also, try to render the same thing on battery power. the power may be fluctuating and causing signal distortion on the cables between your gpu and monitor.